# Add new row with value from previous row +1 in couple threads

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, multithreading, t-sql

I have a table 'testTable':

```
[Id]    [Name]
 0     'something'
 1     'something'
 2     'something'
 3     'something'
```

Id column is not Identity, but primary key, so I add values as

```
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES (2, 'something')
```

I need to have C# method with takes only `[Name]` column, insert this parameter in table and returns the `[Id]` column's value.

Example: I call method with passed string 'test'. The result should be:

1) inserted row in table with `[Id]` = 4 and `[Name]` = 'test'

2) method returns `[Id]` which is 4

I've implemented method which have SQL query like:

```
  declare @Id int;
 set @Id = ISNULL((SELECT MAX(ID) FROM testTable) + 1, 0);

 insert into testTable OUTPUT @Id  values (@Id, @name);
```

For single thread it works fine. But if I call this method, for example, in

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, <lambda with method>);
```

I catch exception an

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'ID_PK'. Cannot insert duplicate
>   key in object 'testTable'

I guess I can use C# `lock` keyword, but it would be great if it's possible to use only SQL query. Thanks.

Comment: You want to insert multiple values into database using multiple threads?

Comment: Can I ask why you are not using identity for the `Id` column? `Identity` is really recommended for this kind of scenario, you just don't need to worry about the issue you have at the moment...

Comment: 1) Yes, it could be case when multiple clients add record to this table in one time, its not adding many records from one client (yes, I know about bulk:)).

Comment: 2) It's an architecture of database (for example it could be case when Id is the same, but Name is different)

Comment: You can check `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` here -  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx and I think this could be done with `SERIALIZABLE` level

Answer (score 1):

You should create an identity column but you can not always control the database design.

When I run into the situation I use an helper method

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a non-query with a retry to handle collisions with non-identity keys
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>The command is retried while unique constraint or duplicate key errors occur
    /// <note type="caution">To be meaningful the command must try different values on each try
    /// e.g. INSERT INTO.. (Key) VALUES (SELECT MAX(Key)+1, ...</note></remarks>
    /// <param name="command">Command to execute</param>
    /// <param name="retries">Maximum number of retries</param>
    /// <returns>Number of rows affected. </returns>
    public static int ExecuteNonQueryWithRetry(this SqlCommand command, int retries) {
        for (int failCount = 0;;) {
            try {
                return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex) {
                const int UniqueConstraintViolation = 2627;
                const int DuplicateKey = 2601;

                if (++failCount >= retries || 
                    (ex.Number != UniqueConstraintViolation &&
                     ex.Number != DuplicateKey))
                    throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

The helper method is used like this:

```
var command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO testTable ( " +
                      "   ID " +
                      "  ,... " +
                      " ) " +
                      " VALUES ( " +
                      "    (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(Id), 0) + 1 " + 
                      "     FROM testTable) " +
                      "   ,... " +
                      " )";
// assign parameter, connection etc

const int MaxRetries = 2;

if (command.ExecuteNonQueryWithRetry(MaxRetries) != 1)
    throw new Exception("Oops");
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe there are more ways how to solve my problem? Sorry, but as for me - it's a bit dirty hack :)

Comment: The dirty hack is the database design :-). The non-hack way is probably the ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE route but it opens another  can of worms (e.g. restoring isolation level after the query)